# Twig Template doesn't recognize Javascript

Tags: javascript, twig, symfony

I am trying to [load custom checkboxes](https://codepen.io/chusquero/pen/XJPMjW) into my Twig template. But no matter what I try it always gives me `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` exception.

I tried this at first

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="{{ assert('path_to_script.js') }}"></script>
```

But it didn't work, then I used `Assetic`, installed by following the documentation and did this

```
{% javascripts 'path_to_script.js' %}
            <script  src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

I tried adding `type="text/javascript"` but still nothing. I also tried putting above script inside a block

```
{% block javascripts %}
   // {% javascripts .... %}
{% endblock %}
```

I tried changing the script header aswell to this

```
$(window).load(function() { ... }
```

But in vain.

I tried adding a `<footer> script call here </footer>` at the end of the page but it didn't work.

I used the compiled CSS by the way else it wont load anything. now it just loads without working.

Am i missing something or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Seems, your `jQuery` library is not included properly in your code.. Check its path.

Comment: I have checked your pen.. It works fine for me.. I guess your `jQuery` inclusion might be pointing to some CDN link which might be getting blocked by your firewall.

Comment: you included it in a twig file and it worked? if so how did you include it and what `Jquery` version did you use

Comment: I didn't make any change your to pen. :)

Comment: the pen works its when i put it in a twig template that it doesn't

Comment: I see.. In that case can you try replacing `$(document).ready(function()` with `$(window).load(function()` and see if it is working?

Comment: i did and it doesn't work

Comment: Did you make a spelling mistake? You have: `src="{{ assert('path_to_script.js') }}"` but instead should be: `src="{{ asset('path_to_script.js') }}"`. Let me know if that fixes anything and I can post as an answer.

Comment: ah yes spelling mistake my bad thank you anyways but that wasn't the issue i fixed it. i had to call some scripts that allow the script to run but i thought that having them on the main page would be enough

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem as i wasn't calling the proper scripts that makes the execution of what i want possible (i.e JS Scripts)